# How to pin a package in dnf (Fedora)

Tags: dnf

I've got a temporary situation where I'm working with pre-release F27, and need to keep one package to a specific (working) version and not be upgraded until the subsequent versions stop breaking something. I know in general "you don't really want to do this", but as I said, it's a temporary dealing with a pre-rel system. You can "pin" packages with the apt system, but I can't locate anything equivalent for dnf.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The `excludepkgs` configuration option in `dnf.conf` lists packages that `dnf` should never try to install or upgrade; in a repo section it affects only that repo, in `[main]` all repos are affected. See the `dnf.conf(5)` man page for details.

Comment: After a misstep or two, that seems to work. Thanks!

Comment: @mats-wichmann please accept the answer as it was helpful for you (for me as well)

Answer (score 20):

The Fedora docs now have a [Quick Doc](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/dnf/#exclude-package) to address this question.  To summarize here:

To **pin** a package, there is the `versionlock` plugin available as part of `dnf-plugins-core` package.  See `man dnf-versionlock`.

```
sudo dnf install 'dnf-command(versionlock)'

sudo dnf versionlock add <package-name-spec>
sudo dnf versionlock delete <package-name-spec>
sudo dnf versionlock list
sudo dnf versionlock clear    # Removes all versionlocks
sudo dnf versionlock exclude  # Also possible here
```

To **exclude** a package from a transaction

```
sudo dnf upgrade --exclude=packagename
```

or add to `/etc/dnf/dnf.conf`

```
excludepkgs=package-name   // See `man dnf.conf` for more
```

The difference between **excluding** and **pinning** (dnf: `versionlock`) is that to *exclude* a package is to tell `dnf` to ignore a package from a transaction entirely, whereas to *versionlock* a package is to recognize the package but explicitly request that it be held at a specific version.  The distinction is important because excluding a package also applies to `dnf search`, `dnf repoquery`, etc. and is effectively to operate as if the package didn't exist.

Hence for the question:

- You probably want to `versionlock` since this does exactly what you want.  This will also help remind you that you have a package pinned since you can `dnf updateinfo --list` and still see that a later version is available, which is not true if it has been `exclude`-ed.  Aside: a `dnf check-update` will not show a pinned (or excluded) package, since literally in this sense there is nothing to update.
- In contrast, to `exclude` a package is a broader statement - perhaps you (or your sysadmin) doesn't want to touch a set of packages at all or simply because you want to ignore a package during some set of transactions for some reason.

  For example, `exclude` applies equally to

  ```
    dnf search <keywords> --exclude=packagename
  ```

Finally, a note that the above applies directly to the given `package-name`, independent of its dependencies.  However, I observe that a `dnf update` will still correctly refuse to update any packages that would break due to a held package (and will helpfully tell you that these are being skipped).

Answer (score 2):

Excluding can also be obtained using `--exclude=package`, but "excluding" and "pinning" are different actions, hence the correct solution for pinning is to use:

```
python3-dnf-plugin-versionlock
```

which replaces:

```
yum-plugin-versionlock
```

there is a difference in the way, the configuration file works between yum and dnf and <del>I don't have a correct answer for dnf (I didn't go through the man page yet). Hence I am not adding furter details.</del> it seems that it was inverted the order used to specify package and epoc number.
dnf man-page does not mention "epoc" (you can check an older system for this man page).

in yum it was:

`"${epoch}:${pkg_name}-${pkg_version}.*"`

in dnf it is:

`"${pkg_name}-${epoch}:${pkg_version}.*"`

to understand, what this means, you can run for instance:

`dnf versionlock add bash`

and check the content of the file:

```
cat /etc/dnf/plugins/versionlock.list

# Added locks on Fri Aug 28 17:30:58 2020
bash-0:4.4.19-10.el8.*
```

Comment: Since your answer seems to have come in several years after the accepted one can you highlight why, in your opinion, this plugin in superior to the  accepted answer which doesn't require additional software?

Comment: @nhed "pinning" and "excluding" are entirely different actions. If you install a server from scratch, if you exclude a package, you will only stick with its initial version, but not a specific pinned version. And it can be a different version. If you have a twin server, and you want the same versin, or if your testing is based on a specific version, you have to use pinning.

Comment: ok, this should probably be integrated into your answer.  But for the OP's scenario where he already has something that works and he wants to just buy some time till a problem is fixed I suspect either will work and with the accepted solution he does not  need to install any plugins.  The real pinning seems useful for reproducible builds etc